# Is there a way to fix broken syntax highlighting in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, syntax-highlighting

I am currently working on a project that is based in Visual Studio 2012 and as soon as I start editing any source file, even if the syntax is correct and compiles, I still get broken highlighting.
[image: Broken C++ syntax highlighting]

Does anyone know what could be causing this? Am I missing an extension?

I am able to change the syntax highlighting colors which means I indeed have an extension installed for C++ language highlighting. However, as soon as I modify some code, all the code below that line will start losing its highlighting and produce glitches, also placing red squiggly lines under text, appearing as an error, even though there are none.

Comment: That's not a syntax highlighting problem, looks more like a video driver issue.  VS2012 is too long ago, on recent versions you could turn off Tools > Options > Environment > General > "Use hardware acceleration"

Comment: I feel your pain if you're trapped into legacy work with VS 2012, but if you can, strongly consider upgrading. VS2015, for example, was a watershed moment, a massive improvement in tool quality in the compiler alone, that you shouldn't have to miss out on.

Comment: I am not sure about how far this goes back however I know that Visual Studio 2019 will load VS2013 projects and use the VS2013 compiler and tools to build as long as you did not agree to upgrade the project file the first time when it asks you to do so.